# Interpolating in Google chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
            google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {

              // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
             // var data = new google.visualization.DataTable('<>');
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Generation', 'Descendants'],[0,300], [85,300],[125,0] ]);


              var options = {
                      title: 'Derating chart',
                          // Draw a trendline for data series 0.
                     lineWidth: 2,       
                      hAxis: {title: 'Temperature [°C]', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}, logScale: false},
                      vAxis: {
                          title: "Irms [A]", 

                          maxValue:8


                      },
                      pointSize:5

                    };


              // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
              // Do not forget to check your div ID
              var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
              chart.draw(data, options);
            }
            </script>
```

[image: Result of the script]

It's quite simple, but I have the following problem:
- In my chart I have 3 points, is it possible to interpolate the values between that points? I need to display the values between them when you put the mouse over the line

Comment: You mean when hovering the line instead of the point showing 0-85 for first section and 85-125 for second section?

Comment: yes, exactly. It should be something like get the X-axis value and the y-value when the mouse is over the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be an option for this... but checking forums and documentation have found none. Closest to this is using a trendline, but values don´t match your line. So your only way is doing something manually. Here is a workaround I made using jquery :

```
//you need to have in options tooltip:{isHtml:true} for this to work

         google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function(){
              $('#chart_div svg path').mousemove(function(e){
                  $('.google-visualization-tooltip').remove(); // remove previous tooltips
                  var x=e.offsetX; // get x coordinate
                  var y=e.offsetY; //get y coordinate
                  var xValue= Math.round(chart.getChartLayoutInterface().getHAxisValue(x)); // get chart x value at coordinate
                  var yValue=Math.round( chart.getChartLayoutInterface().getVAxisValue(y)); // get chart y value at coordinate
                  // create tooltip
                  var tootlip = $('<div class= "google-visualization-tooltip"><ul class="google-visualization-tooltip-item-list"><li class="google-visualization-tooltip-item"><span >X : '+xValue+'</span></li><li class="google-visualization-tooltip-item"><span>Y : '+yValue+'</span></li></ul></div>'); 
                  tootlip.css({position:'absolute', left:(x+20)+'px', top:(y-100)+'px', width:'100px', height:'70px'}) // set tooltip position
                  $('#chart_div').append(tootlip);  // add tooltip to chart

              })

              $('#chart_div svg path').mouseout(function(e){
                  $('.google-visualization-tooltip').remove();

              })

          })
```

Full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/48ouLbmm/

Note: without the mouseout it works better, but tooltip stays until next mouseover